# convert base64 to image to dispaly in input type="file" -React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, file, base64url

I have form with 4 pages , written in react. when I am clicking on next page the form data of this page are saved in sessionStorage and move to next page. so that if I am returning the previous page the form takes its values from the storage.
My problem is with the pictures.
I upload an image in an input that accepts image files.
and saves it in storage after converting to base64.

The problem is that when I go back, I can't get the image to be displayed in the input.
(And don't send the photo in axios after I get to the last page)
I would very much appreciate your answers.
here I am setting the image:```

```
 const getBase64FromUrl = async (url) => {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await data.blob();
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        const base64data = reader.result;
        sessionStorage.setItem("deceasedPhoto", base64data)
        resolve(base64data)
      };
    });
  };


  const handleChange = function loadFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      getBase64FromUrl(file)
      setFile({
        url: file,
        file: event.target.files[0],
        name: event.target.files[0].name,
      });

    }
  };
```

```
 <>
                <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
                  <Input
                    accept="image/*"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    file={file.file}
                    id="icon-button-file"
                    type="file"
                    sx={{ display: "none" }}
                  />
                  <IconButton
                    sx={{ bgcolor: "#000000", m: 0 }}
                    aria-label="upload picture"
                    component="span"
                  >
                    <PhotoCamera
                      sx={{ color: "#ffffff", height: 12, width: 12, p: 0 }}
                    />
                  </IconButton>
                </label>
```

and here how I try to get it in useffect hook when page mounted:`

```
  const [file, setFile] = useState({ url: "", file: "", name: "" });
```

```
function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {

    var arr = dataurl.split(','),
      mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
      bstr = atob(arr[1]),
      n = bstr.length,
      u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

    while (n--) {
      u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }

    return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
  }
```

`````
useEffect(() => {
 
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("deceasedPhoto")) {

      var file = dataURLtoFile(sessionStorage.getItem("deceasedPhoto"), 'hello.png');

      setFile({ url: "", file: file, name: "" })
    }
  }, [])

````your text`
`````

Comment: `<input type="file" />` does not display images. If you want to display an image, you need to use an `<img />` tag.

Comment: So why do I need to convert base64? For it to be displayed? When I upload a picture it is displayed there.it it mui material's Input component  and have accept="image/*"